# Unable to send input data to jsp using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am trying to send input data entered in text box from my html file to JSP using Ajax. I am able to receive data from the JSP file and print it on my HTML page but I am not able to send the data entered in the input field to JSP.

I am setting the URL field in my Ajax function but when when I do a get parameter using JSP on the URL it does not seem to work.

```
String integerlist = request.getParameter("value1");    
String nthnumber = request.getParameter("value2");
```

Is this the correct way of sending data to JSP page ?

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var value1= document.getElementById("list").value;
        var value2= document.getElementById("nthnumber").value;
        var url = 'solution.jsp?value1='+value1+'&value2='+value2;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
 <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <PRE>
     <B>Enter List of Integers (Note that duplicates are allowed):&nbsp;</B>  <input type="text" name="list" value="" id="list" /><br />

      <B>Enter to find the N-th largest element in the supplied list:</B> <input type="text" name="nthnumber" value="" id="nthnumber"  /><br />

      <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

      <B><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="loadXMLDoc()" > &nbsp; <input type="submit" name="clear" value="  Clear  "></B>
    </PRE>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

And another JSP file:

```
    <%@ page  language="java" import="java.util.*" errorPage="" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Set" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.TreeSet" %>

     <%  
        String integerlist = request.getParameter("value1");  // requesting the list of integer values 
        String nthnumber = request.getParameter("value2");   // requesting the nth number  

        // String integerlist = "5,3,80,75,25,90,1";
        int nthnumber =  Integer.parseInt(nthnumber1);

        String[] arraylist= integerlist.split(","); // splitting the requested string based on the delimiter 

        int[] results = new int[arraylist.length]; // creating integer array on the fly based on the arraylist received  

        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {
            results[i] = Integer.parseInt(arraylist[i]);
        }       
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < results.length; j++) {
                if (results[i] < results[j]) {
                    int swap = results[i];
                    results[i] = results[j];
                    results[j]=swap;
                }
                if (results[i] == results[j]) {
                    results[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    %>
    <%=""+ results[nthnumber-1]%>
```

Comment: no , you need to call the URL as well , like $.get(url);

Comment: @Satya he didn't say he is using jQuery

Comment: actually i had a silly error which i just noticed i had declared the same string variable twice in my code and it seems to be passing the input now. I just updated the code. However, is this the best way to implement without using jQuery ?

Comment: @user3157309 Your Code seems to be fine , Just add an exception block if something goes wrong with AJAX response in your else part.